# What would you call a class that is never intended to be instantiated in C#?

Tags: c#, class, static

What would you call a class that is never intended to be instantiated in C#?

For example, I put all my class files in a folder called Objects, however, now I want a class that just contains static methods that controls the use of other Objects, but will never be instantiated itself, and I don't know where to put it in my file structure or what to call it!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call that Static class. you can put it in a helper folder and call it either `XxxUtil` or `XxxHelper`.

Answer (score 3):

Typically I suffix such types with the name Utils.

```
public static class ObjectUtils {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As DarthVader suggested, `XXXUtil` and `XXXHelper` are good names. If the static class contains extension methods, then I call it `XxxExtension`.

```
public static class StringExtension
{

    public static double ToDouble(this string myString)
    {
         return double.Parse(myString);
    }

}
```